# Why Generic Rigs won't matching? ( Unity )

Tags: unity, animation, blender, skeletal-animation, import

**1 part - Blender**
I made a character with animations in Blender. When importing in Unity, I decided to split the Armature and the Model into different FBX files.

This is how we get 2 files:
`1 FBX anim` - It contain Rig and Animations.
`2 FBX model` - It contain Model and Rig ( without animations).

Blender Export settings:
[image]
[image]

**2 part - Unity**

Both FBX use Generic Rig.

I mapped animations from `1 FBX anim` to `2 FBX model` by assigning Generic Avatar from `1 FBX anim` to `2 FBX model`. After that, I added `2 FBX model` to the scene and add an Animator on it, which had an Avatar and Animations of the `1 FBX anim`.

I started testing animations and saw these errors in the Animation window.
[image]

It is interesting that if the `1 FBX anim` is exported from Blendr with an Armature and aModel in it, then everything will start working and the errors will disappear.

Why it happens? Before that, I have done similar procedures with my other projects and characters. Everything worked, only now Unity gives error and demands that `1 FBX anim` must be not only with Rig and Animations but also with a Model.

Comment: It looks like this question is about the same errors described in your other recent question. You might want to wait until you get answers to just one of these questions before posting another one. The answer to one might clear up both issues.

Comment: First question about why missing bones error exist while animation works perfectly. Second question ( this question) about why missing bones error show up only if FBX with animations consists of a Rig and Animation. But if FBX with aniations consists of more than just a Rig and Animation, the error will disappear and the animation will work.

Comment: That sounds like it could be one question about "help me understand these missing bones errors" to keep the information centralized in one place.

Comment: This error occurs if the animation does not find a bone to animate. But my questions are not about the nature of the error. I would like to at least know the answer to one of my questions - Why is this error shown when everything is working fine?